# How do I use one UIViewController and two UIPickerViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

There are some older posts on this but I couldn't get them to work (I tried using the tag method below). I want to use two `UIPickerView` in one `UIViewController` in Swift but I can't figure out how to delineate them:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,     UIPickerViewDataSource {



var footballWinner = [
    2015: "Patriots"
]

var hockeyWinner = [
    2015: "TBD"
]

var baseballWinner = [
    2015: "TBD"
]

var baseketballWinner = [
    2015: "TBD"
]



@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var sportPicker: UIPickerView!

 @IBOutlet weak var yearPicker: UIPickerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yearPicker.delegate = self
    yearPicker.dataSource = self
    sportPicker.delegate = self
    sportPicker.dataSource = self
}

if UIPickerView, didSelectRow == sportPIcker

class YearPickerClass {

    var years = [2015, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010]

    var selectedYear: Int?

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return years.count
}

func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedYear = years[row]
}

func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return "\(years[row])"
}
}

class SportPickerClass {

      var sports = ["Football", "Baseball", "Hockey", "Basketball"]

    var selectedSport: String?

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return sports.count
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedSport = sports[row]
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(sports[row])"
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: You're either going to need to use if statements in the data source and delegate methods to check which pickerView was selected or combine both lists to be different components in one pickerView, or a third option is to pass off delegation and the data source to some arbitrary object

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing classes to do this? (see edited code)  But I'm not sure how to form my if statement to test which picker is selected?

Comment: You need to make `SportPickerClass` conform to `UIPickerViewDataSource`  --> `class SportPickerClass: UIPickerViewDataSource` then when you are setting `sportPicker.dataSource` instead of self, you set it to an instance of  `SportPickerClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an arbitrary object that conforms to the `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` (or just one or the other) and then set the `delegate` and/or `dataSource` to this object like so (for simplicity I created two classes, but one could easily create one class with a convenience init that takes an array as a parameter):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPickerView: UIPickerView!

    let firstPickerData = FirstPickerData()
    let secondPickerData = SecondPickerData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstPickerView.delegate = firstPickerData
        firstPickerView.dataSource = firstPickerData

        secondPickerView.delegate = secondPickerData
        secondPickerView.dataSource = secondPickerData

    }
}

class FirstPickerData: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let source = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return source.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return source[row]
    }
}

class SecondPickerData: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let source = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return source.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return source[row]
    }
}
```